# watermark commend for ff-mpeg batch converter

Tags: ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I used [FFmpeg Batch Converter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-batch/) for video converting. I used the below command

```
-c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy
```

Now I want to add a watermark too.

```
logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=50:50" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy
```

but it does not work. Could you help me how can I write the above code to add water mark with having control on the watermark size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use this

```
ffmpeg -i YourvideoInput.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" YourvideoInput.mp4
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work in "ff-mpeg batch converter"